# Is there a hook (or equivalent solution) for "right at the end of the test" for WebdriverIO?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I've been going round in circles a bit on this - and I'm not convinced it's possible - hoping someone can prove me wrong!

In WebdriverIO, I have a test suite something like (dramatically simplified here!):

```
describe ('My suite', function () {
  it ('Is the first test', function () {
     expect(1).to.equal(2);
  });
  it ('Is the second test', function () {
     expect(2).to.equal(2);
  });
});
```

What I would like to do is have some sort of hook called at the end of each of my two tests, but with code that would include a further "common across all tests at the end" assertion, and as such can impact the result of the test - hence why "afterTest" is no good. Obviously I can just repeat the code, or have a function defined and a call to it in each test, but can anyone offer a way of doing it as a hook of some sort, so there is no need to actually include a call to it at the end of each test - just an automatic, or implied call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is really possible ✅. Please refer the below code. Require the test file which is containing the it() block and delete it from cache before the next actual it() block begins to execute. I have attached the execution screenshot.

***spec.js***

```
describe('Basic checks for internet app', () => {

  let resolved

  it('should have the right title', async () => {
    await browser.url('https://webdriver.io');
    const title = await browser.getTitle();
    assert.strictEqual(title, 'WebdriverIO · Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js');
    require('./test');
    resolved = require.resolve('./test');
    delete require.cache[resolved];
  })



  it('should assert the wrong right title', async () => {
    await browser.url('https://webdriver.io');
    const title = await browser.getTitle();
    return assert.strictEqual(title, 'Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js');
    require('./test');
    resolved = require.resolve('./test');
    delete require.cache[resolved];
  })


})
```

***test.js***

```
import assert from 'assert';

    assert.equal(2, 2)
```

[image]

**(OR)**

If you want this to be a separate test follow below

***spec.js***

```
describe('Basic checks for internet app', () => {

  let resolved

  it('should have the right title', async () => {
    await browser.url('https://webdriver.io');
    const title = await browser.getTitle();
    return assert.strictEqual(title, 'WebdriverIO · Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js');
  })

  require('./test');
  resolved = require.resolve('./test');
  delete require.cache[resolved];

  it('should assert the wrong right title', async () => {
    await browser.url('https://webdriver.io');
    const title = await browser.getTitle();
    return assert.strictEqual(title, 'Next-gen WebDriver test framework for Node.js');
  })

  require('./test');
  resolved = require.resolve('./test');
  delete require.cache[resolved];


})
```

***test.js***

```
import assert from 'assert';

it('should be executed', () => {

    assert.equal(2, 2)

})
```

[image]

Comment: My opinion is that test.js is treated as a separate test rather than how it will be if it is a hook. Is there a way it can impact the result of the previous test itself?

Comment: You can require this JS file from inside the it() block. And we need to remove the it() in test.js file having the assertions and rest untouched.

Comment: @Raju I have edited the answer and uploaded the screenshot. I have provided both the option.

Comment: Hi @BharathKumarS - Thanks for your efforts on this. Unfortunately, while your first solution (where test.js did not include it's own 'it' block) was close, this solution still has the same problem I'm trying to avoid - I don't want to have to have repeated code (eg a require call to test.js) in every test. I was hoping to do it with a hook - a bit like 'afterEach' for example - but the problem with afterEach is that by the time it is executed, the current test has finished, and the afterEach code has no effect on the test result...

Comment: What I'm actually doing, to give more context, is using a try/catch block across multiple asserts in a number of tests, and then I want a wrapper hook / function at the end of each test to throw the errors for that test, before moving on to the next test, if that makes sense!